# Simple regex does not work in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Looks like a simple question. But I simply don't understand:

This piece of htaccess rules do work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m(.+)$ ?s=$1
```

But this does not:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?s=$1
```

It returns an **Internal Server Error**. What's wrong with that regex? What should be altered in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "does not work" exactly means, but I think it might get stuck in a rewrite loop.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^?s=
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?s=$1
```

I haven't tested this, but what it should do is only rewrite if there hasn't already been a ?s parameter added.

Comment: It doesn't work. I solved it—or more precisely, settled it—using `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?s=$1` (so the dot disappears out of the regex). But the question remains: Why doesn't `^(.+)$` work?

Comment: Probably the same reason, the dot also includes the ?= part, so it tries to keep rewriting it (making it ?s=?s=, ?s=?s=?s=, etc). By limiting it to URIs that start with a letter it excludes the ?, essentially doing the same I tried to make.

Comment: I also think I know what I did wrong, I should have escaped the ? (which has a special function in regex).

Comment: But `^([^?]+)$ ?s=$1` doesn't work either. I should work, shouldn't it? I'm trying to negate the character `?`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I can't test anything now so I wouldn't know how else to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just realised you can also look for the actual query string in RewriteConds. You could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !s=
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?s=$1
```